# Setuptools -- Replacing Manifest.in with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, pep517, sdist

Does setuptools support replacing the Manifest.in file, which specifies files that should only be included in the sdist distribution with a declaration in pyproject.toml?

Comment: As far as I know, you can do without it if you have a normal/common package structure. But if you have some complicated requirements about what should and should not go into the sdist, you still need to use the `MANIFEST.in` file unfortunately.

Comment: There is an open issue for setuptools to pick up this feature, at this time of this writing it is still open.

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3341

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setuptools does not currently support replacing the `MANIFEST.in` with a declaration in `pyproject.toml`.

There is also currently no [specification](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/) for how to control the files included in an sdist.

There are other build backends which do support this, by using their own `tool` subsection of `pyproject.toml`. For example, [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/plugins/builder/sdist/#default-file-selection) uses `[tool.hatch.build.targets.sdist]` to control the sdist content, see [File selection](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#file-selection) for more details about that.